# Unparsable structured data errors in GSC depsite schema checking out on Structured Data Testing tool

Tags: html, google-chrome, schema, google-search-console, structured-data

I made some product schema that for the longest time was valid and now all of sudden in the last week or see is failing to pass on GSC. I even tested the same schema on the Structured Data Tool and it checks out there.

Here is an example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Review",
    "itemReviewed": {
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Osprey Farpoint Trek 75",
      "material": "420HD Nylon Packcloth",      "description": "The Osprey Farpoint Trek 75 is touted as a hyrbid between a travel backpack and a trekking backpack. So does it deliever? Let's find out...",     "brand": "Osprey",
      "image": "https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/osprey-farpoint-trek-75-review-10-690x460.jpg",
      "review": {
                        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
         "ratingValue": "4.5",
          "bestRating": "5",
          "worstRating": "0"
        },
                "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "Ralph Cope"
        }
      }
    },
   "dateCreated": "November 4 2019",
    "dateModified": "January 21 2021",
        "reviewRating": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": "4.5",
      "bestRating": "5",
      "worstRating": "0"
    },
        "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Ralph Cope"
    },
    "publisher": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "The Broke Backpacker",
      "logo": "https://8ut3vnmqb148491id57v2rl2-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-correct-size-e1403259130731-small.png"
    }
      }
  </script>
```

GSC flagged the very first curly bracket as an error.

Please help me understand what's going on here. Can't figure out why GSC is suddenly breaking my balls! Did Google change its schema standards overnight perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide what specific error you are getting from it?

Comment: The tool JSON/LD Playground ( https://json-ld.org/playground/ ) also reports an error in your markup.

Comment: @StuFurlong Here is a screenshot of the unparsable error GSC is feeding me: https://prnt.sc/11891bv It's just the first curly bracket.

Comment: @roamingralph - This might sound crazy, but have you tried changing the `@context` for http://schema.org to be `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: @StuFurlong Yep tried https. No change :/